# Samsung Kies program on my PC can't restore contacts to Samsung Galaxy S

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-kies

I downloaded a new program, and I already did a backup using the [Samsung Kies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Kies) program installed on my PC, but now I can't restore the contacts because the program is not recognizing the phone, and I can't choose the restore button.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Disconnect your phone, use Kies to reinstall the drivers on your PC, then reboot both.  And maybe edit the question to complete it :)

Comment: it's not working.I even downloaded an update for the kies program but still it's not recognizing the phone

Comment: Have you altered your phone software in any way?

Comment: yup..I did and when I found out that I couldn't restore my contacts back I downloded a software which is suposed to be the same as the old one . still no use

Comment: What's the "__new program__" you are referring to?